# react hooks props undefined again

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, undefined, react-props

I am trying to send a hard coded array from my App.js to a component called 'Select'. It looks exactly the same as a tutorial I am following. Maybe someone else can see what I am doing wrong.

The state variable 'categories' is defined in App.js and undefined in select.js

```
import {useState} from "react";
import Header from "./components/header";
import Select from "./components/select.js";


function App(){
    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([
            {
                id: 1,
                name:'Restaurant',
                pros:['Great Menu, good food, Great Beer list, live music'],
                cons:['Bad acoustics, bad service, rude staff, over priced']
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name:'Music Venue',
                pros:['Good seating, Music Variety, Good Dance Floor, Good Bar, Good Food'],
                cons:['Bad acoustics, bad crowd, small space, over priced']
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name:'Hiking Trail',
                pros:['Spectacular Scenery, Great Destination, Swimming, Drinking Water'],
                cons:['Crowded, Horses/Bicycles, Burn Zone, Biting Bugs']
            }
        ]);    
    
    return(
        <div className="container">
            
            <Header />
             
            {categories.length > 0 ?
              <Select options={categories}
              />:' No Options'}
            
        </div>
    )
}
export default App;
```

```
import Option from "./option.js"

const Select = ({categories}) => {
    
   
  {console.log(categories)}
    return (
        <>
        
            <select name="selectCat" id="selectCat">

            <option value="" defaultValue>Choose a Category</option>
            
            {categories && categories.map((option) => (
            
            <Option key={option.id} text={option.name}/>))}
            </select>
            </>
        
    )
}

export default Select
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: in Select component prop to destructure is `options`  and not `categories`.

Comment: You are passing an `options` prop, but destructure `categories`. Voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo".

Comment: Thanks, Shyam and Drew. That was the problem. Variable naming is a problem for me in react. I will try to answer another person's question in your honer

Answer (score 0):

You are passing wrong prop name. Change `options` to `categories`

```
<Select 
   categories={categories} <- here
 />:' No Options'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Option from "./option.js"

const Select = ({categories}) => {
    
   
  {console.log(categories)}
    return (
        <>
        
            <select name="selectCat" id="selectCat">

            <option value="" defaultValue>Choose a Category</option>
            
            {categories && categories.map((option) => (
            
            <Option key={option.id} text={option.name}/>))}
            </select>
            </>
        
    )
}

export default Select
```

You're passing options but destructuring categories. So instead try destructuring options.

```
const Select = ({options}) => {
```